# How to authenticate a user and get his acount details in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I am new to UWP and I am trying to make an app that includes sign in with Microsoft account. The problem is that I got very confused what API should I use and how to make the authentication.

After very long search I found that Microsoft have APIs and SDKs for everything - Outlook, OneDrive, Live, Office365, Microsoft Graph etc. But there is no clear documentation, what developer should use to authenticate a user and get his account details such as name and email.

It seems that the Live SDK could do the trick, but Microsoft state that this SDK is legacy and developers should use OndeDrive SDK. But OneDrive don't suit my needs, I can't get users email address and also I have to have developer account so I can build a sample app to test it. This is too much just for a test, isn't it?

After more research I found that Microsoft Graph could help, but it seems that it is only for business purposes or maybe I am wrong?

So in short what I try to achieve is making an app that let the user sign in with his Microsoft account. After successful authentication I need to get his account details so I can build him a profile in the app. And all of this I want to do it without having to make developer or business accounts.

Hope someone could help, becaouse the Microsoft documentation is very confusing.

Comment: I would go for Azure AD first. It's basically free (for the first 50 000 users) and supports Microsoft, Twitter, Linkedin and google accounts. It is also really simple to use

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph does support the ability for you to sign in with a Microsoft Account, and then access the user's very basic profile and their personal consumer OneDrive and Outlook.  Token acquisition is achieved through the new v2 endpoint (converged auth, that allows you to get a token for the signed in user, whether they are a consumer user through Microsoft Account or a commercial/business/school user through Azure AD).

I recommend taking a look at a couple of places.  One place is https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/converged_auth and here on app registration and token acquisition: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview/ and here for get started for windows apps: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-wpf/.  NOTE:  This last one uses a preview/experimental client library.

Hope this helps,